# Problems running npm install during docker-compose build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker image that installs ubuntu and `RUN`s some additional commands like installing NodeJS.

The Dockerfile (in combination with a `docker-compose.yml`) also mounts a directory to a directory on the host. That looks like this:

```
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/Dev/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    volumes:
      - ./../../src:/src
```

In the `Dockerfile` I have the following lines for a volume:

```
VOLUME ["/src"]
WORKDIR /src
```

When I run the container with `docker-compose up` and then do a `ls -a` inside the mounted `src/` folder of the container, then I see all the files that I also see on the host. So far so good.

(Command I run too look inside container: `docker exec -it <container hash> ls -a`)

Since all files seem to be there, including a `package.json` I added a new `RUN` command to my `Dockerfile` which is: `npm install`. So I have this:

```
VOLUME ["/src"]
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
```

Except that gives me an error that it can't find a `package.json` in the `src/` folder.

When I add a `RUN ls -a` (remember, I switched to the `src/` folder with `WORKDIR`), then it shows that it's an empty directory...

So in `Dockerfile` I have:

```
VOLUME ["/src"]
WORKDIR /src

# shows that /src is empty. If I do 'RUN pwd', then it shows I really am in /src
RUN ls -a 
RUN npm install
```

But still, after I do a `docker-compose up` and then again do a `ls -a` inside the `/src` folder of the container it shows all my source files again.

So my question is, why aren't they there during build time (I'm running `docker-compose build`)?

What is the way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding the difference between the `VOLUME` command in a Dockerfile and the `-v` flag to the `docker` daemon (what `docker-compose` uses for its volumes).

The values under the `volumes` key in your `docker-compose` file tell `docker` what directories to map in *after* your image has finished building. They aren't used during the build process.

Fortunately, you automatically have access to all of your source files, due to the `context` line in your compose file - they're just in the local `src` directory, not your current working directory!

Try updating your Dockerfile to the following:

```
# NOTE: You don't want a VOLUME directive if you only want to mount a local
# directory. WORKDIR is optional, but doesn't matter for my example,
# so I'm omitting it.

# Copy the npm files into your Docker image. If you do this first, the docker
# daemon can cache the built layers, making your images build faster and be 
# substantially smaller, since most of your dependencies will remain unchanged
# between builds.
COPY src/package.json package.json
COPY src/npm-shrinkwrap.json npm-shrinkwrap.json

# Actually install the dependencies.
RUN npm install

# Copy all of your source files from the `src` directory into the Docker image.
COPY src .
```

Now, one problem here: You probably already have your `npm` modules installed under `src/node_modules`. So, you can either ditch everything above except the final `COPY` line, or you can add `src/node_modules` to a `.dockerignore` file in your build root (`../..`).

Comment: I played around with it again. The `COPY` command does the trick in that it copies my `package.json` to the `/src` folder. I can then also do a `RUN npm install`, which also works. It shows that it creates a `node_modules` folder. But then when I run `docker-compose up`, it overwrites everything the `Dockerfile` placed in the `/src` directory. I guess that is because the `docker-compose.yml` does a `-v` on the same `/src` folder, thus overwriting all of its previous content?

Comment: Right. Mounting a local directory will replace any matching contents in the image with the contents from your local drive. You generally only want to do this during development.